# Convert a menu in a java code to a dialog box

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I need to make this menu, using a dialog box (GUI) , and appear in one dialog box. How can I make it ?

```
System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------Menu Options------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\tHere you need to enter a number between 1 and 6 according your choice. ");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("1.Search for a particular student.");
            System.out.println("2.Show students names, marks and grades.");
            System.out.println("3.Display passes.");
            System.out.println("4.Display failures.");
            System.out.println("5.Show statistics.");
            System.out.println("6.Exit.");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Enter you choice");
            option=Keyboard.readInt();
            switch (option)
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: Use Java Swing or awi Packages for Making GUI

Comment: i didnt understand...what do i need to write ? thanks

Comment: @user2999246 As i mention above with the help of above packages we can make GUI For more http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: but to include a bulk of text like my code above, what do i need to write, is there is something like JOption... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 String ques = "<html><body><b>-----------------Menu Options--------------</b><br/>"
            + "Here you need to enter a number between 1 and 6 according your choice.<br/>"
            + "----------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>"
            + "1.Search for a particular student.<br/>"
            + "2.Show students names, marks and grades.<br/>"
            + "3.Display passes.<br/>"
            + "4.Display failures.<br/>"
            + "5.Show statistics.<br/>"
            + "6.Exit.<br/>"
            + "Enter you choice<br/></body></html>";
     int opt = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ques));
     System.out.println(opt);
```

Comment: If representing a list in HTML, it is better to use `<ol>`/`<li>` than `<br />`.  This would probably be better suited to a an array of options, as passed to [`showInputDialog(Object,String,int,Icon,Object[],Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29).